# ZF2 Redirect to route with controller action

Tags: zend-framework2

In module.config.php i added:

```
    'logout' => array(
        'type' => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/logout',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'Index',
                'action'        => 'logout',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

in IndexController.php added:

```
public function logoutAction() {
    $this->getSessionStorage()->forgetMe();
    $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->clear("email");
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users', array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

and always redirects to http://localhost/users but should to http://localhost/users/login/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Redirect::toRoute()` the first argument is the name of the route you define in `module.config.php`. For example the route you mentioned is defined as `logout`.

```
'logout' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/logout',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'Index',
            'action'        => 'logout',
        ),
    ),
),
```

So to redirect to this route use the following line.

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('logout')
```

There is no need to provide the controller and/or action as second argument because you already configured that at the `options` of the route.

Comment: okay, but when i used $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL, array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'index')) In firefox i saw: incorrect forwarding

Comment: That is because instead of the route name you provide `null` as the first argument. And you don't have to provide the second argument `array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'index')`.